# nodejs application cannot efficiently process concurrent requests

Tags: node.js, concurrency

I am managing a server running a nodejs (next.js) application, which for the moment I am treating as a black box. I am running that application using `pm2` in fork mode using `ecosystem.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "app-frontend-nextjs",
      cwd: "/home/user/app/frontend-nextjs",
      script: "npm",
      args: "start",
      env: {}
    }
  ]
};
```

Running `pm2 list` results in:

```
┌─────┬────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                   │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ app-frontend-nextjs    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 2413063  │ 27D    │ 5    │ online    │ 0%       │ 64.6mb   │ xxxxxx   │ disabled │
└─────┴────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
host metrics | cpu: 2.3% | mem free: 62.0% | ens3: ⇓ 0mb/s ⇑ 0mb/s | disk: ⇓ 0mb/s ⇑ 0mb/s /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 67.4% |
```

The application serves responses to http requests, and to assemble those it does some (or a lot of) API calls to a locally installed Drupal website. The Drupal website responds pretty fast on single or concurrent requests and is not part of the problem.

A response from the application usually needs ~7.5 seconds to be generated:

```
$ curl -s -w 'seconds %{time_total}\n' -I 127.0.0.1:3000 | grep seconds
seconds 7.568871
```

This is very slow, but it's not the root cause of the problem.

If I make 3 requests concurrently, then usually the first one will finish in ~7.5 seconds and the other 2 in ~22 seconds:

```
$ curl -s -w 'seconds %{time_total}\n' -I 127.0.0.1:3000 | grep seconds &
[1] 482148
$ curl -s -w 'seconds %{time_total}\n' -I 127.0.0.1:3000 | grep seconds &
[2] 482150
$ curl -s -w 'seconds %{time_total}\n' -I 127.0.0.1:3000 | grep seconds &
[3] 482152
$
$ seconds 7.809088
seconds 22.355956
seconds 22.355522
```

Note that 3 x 7.5 = 22.5 so it's as if some requests will wait for all of the others to finish.

I executed the test with 6 requests and the response times were:

```
seconds 7.580153
seconds 14.922243
seconds 43.844184
seconds 43.841478
seconds 43.844960
seconds 43.848788
```

Which confirms that some of the responses wait for evey other response to finish.

The fact that the majority of the parallel responses complete in exactly the same amount of time (to the millisecond level) smells bad and reveals that there is something weird going on. Something is blocking the dispatch of those responses until all of them have completed processing.

Why does the application exhibit this behavior? Is is because I run the application in "fork" mode or should I start having a look on the code of the application in case there is some mysterious locking logic which causes this behavior?

Comment: I can almost guarantee that the [event loop is being blocked](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking) by a time consuming task that isn't being executed asynchronously. I have seen one person fired for doing this despite being shown how to write non-blocking code several times. It will be difficult to debug without seeing the code involved in those requests but start by looking at i/o, file reads, looping. Anything that looks like it would logically take time to complete.

Comment: Are you sure to launch it in production mode ? Also check the database if the connection is correctly done

Answer (score 0):

Node code can run both synchronously (do it in order, don't continue until done) and asynchronously (do it now, don't care if somethings not done yet).

That behavior shows there is probably some of the former going in on your app's logic. A good way to confirm this would be to check logs on the drupal site to see how your app is accessing it.

If the logs show similar usage at the same time delays, you'll want to verify that your app's code is running as async as it can